# What is the ftp_chdir equivalent in SFTP?

Tags: php, ftp, sftp

I am working on SFTP section (in PHP). I know the function to change the directory after making the connection in FTP which is `ftp_chdir`.

What is the similar function in SFTP?

Is `ssh2_sftp_readlink` the similar one?

Answer (score 4):

The SFTP protocol does not have a concept of a working directory you know from the FTP protocol (or a local system).

So there's no equivalent.

---

Some SFTP libraries (and probably all SFTP clients) can *simulate* the working directory locally. But PHP SSH2 library cannot.

For example, another PHP SFTP implementation, the [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) has `Net_SFTP::chdir` method.

---

In general with SFTP you should use absolute paths. Most SFTP servers also allows you to use relative paths to the account's home directory.

You may find also function `ssh2_sftp_realpath` useful to convert a relative path to an absolute path.

The `ssh2_sftp_realpath(".")` should return an absolute path to the home directory.